# Postgresql query returns NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I'm using Selenium + postgre integration in order to validate correct data on database. After an action on UI then I'm using **Npgsql** library in order to receive scalar value from cell and then use it for assertion.

Code looks line:

```
 public static string GetCreditAmount(string orderId, string accountNumber)
        {
            string findCreditQuery = $@"SELECT ""Credit"" FROM accounting.""AccountLines"" al INNER JOIN accounting.""Accounts"" acc ON al.""Account_FK"" = acc.""Id""
            WHERE
            ""OrderId"" = '{orderId}'
            AND ""AccountNumber"" = '{accountNumber}'
            ORDER BY al.""CreatedDateUtc"" DESC";
            using (var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(Configuration.AdminConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                try
                {
                    var account = connection.ExecuteScalar(findCreditQuery).ToString();
                    return account;
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException e)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                    var account = connection.ExecuteScalar(findCreditQuery).ToString();
                    return account;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem which I'm receiving is **NullReferenceException**, however results are really random. In one test I'm firing & asserting few times where in like 85% it does not work (Null reference) and from time to time in like 15% it works (test passed). Strange case is that assertion which was fine in one run fails in another one.

I was trying to add static sleeps (Thread.Sleep) in order to give database few extra second for proceeding but all it still fails.

Is there any proper solution which can be used?

Comment: What part of the code is getting the error?  Are you sure your query returns data every time?  Your building strings instead of using parameters for your SQL query this could cause some of your issues and leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: Error is always inside: "connection.ExecuteScalar(findCreditQuery).ToString();"

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
object o = null;
string s = o.ToString();
```

I believe you will get the same error.  I believe the issue is your database object is null.

This will probably fix it:

```
object o = connection.ExecuteScalar(findCreditQuery);
string account = o == null ? null : o.ToString();
```

Alternatively, you can implement a `DbDataReader` and use the `IsDbNull` method.  It will be more work but might also be more scalable if you plan to do more than what's currently being done:

```
string account;

using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(findCreditQuery, connection))
{
    using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader.Read();
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
            account = reader.GetString(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: ExecuteScalar doesn't return `null` for a database null - it returns `DBNull`. However, it does return null if there was no resultset at all, e.g. for INSERT.